# Is this set countable or uncountable? (Related to mean value theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be a differentiable function on the real line.

Consider any $h\in (0,1)$. By the mean value theorem there exists $d_h\in (0,h)$ such that $f'(d_h)=\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$.
Is the set $\{d_h\}$ countable or uncountable?

(Update: I wish $h$ to be varied, not fixed. For every new value of $h$, there is this new $d_h$ indexed by $h$ produced by the mean value theorem. So the question is that is the set of all the $d_h$ countable or not.)

There are certainly uncountable choices of $h$, but there may be repetitions such that $d_{h_1}=d_{h_2}$.

Thanks.

Comment: What's $\{d_h\}$? Is it $\{d\in(0,h) | f'(d)=\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\}$ for any fixed $h$ or $\{d\in(0,1) |\text{there exist}\ h\in(0,1)\ \text{such that}\  f'(d)=\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\}$?

Comment: To be clear, you are asking about the size of the set $\{d\in(0,1)|f'(d) = \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\text{ for some }d<h<1\}$, correct?

Comment: @BigbearZzz It is the latter.

Comment: @JoeyZou Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g:(0,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be defined by $g(h) = \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$. Then $g$ is continuous. If $g$ is not constant, then by the intermediate value theorem its range must be uncountable, and hence the set of $d\in(0,1)$ such that $f'(d) = g(h)$ for some $d<h<1$ must also be uncountable. If $g$ is constant, then $f$ is linear, and so $f'(d) = g(h)$ for any $d,h\in(0,1)$, i.e. the desired set is also uncountable.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If $f$ is constant then the set is obviously uncountable.

If $f$ is linear that is $f(x)= ax +b $ then the set is obviously uncountable.
If we treat $h$ as a parameter for non-constant  $f$ and let it vary then the set $\{d_h \}$ is uncountable. 
If $h$ is fixed for non-constant and non-linear analytic $f$ the set is countable.

Comment: How would you prove the part "then the set $\{d_h\}$ is uncountable?

Comment: What's your interpretation of $\{d_h\}$? How did you conclude that if $f$ is non-constant and $h$ held fixed, then $\{d_h\}$ is countable?

Comment: The key is the observation that in the second case the set $(0,h)$ can have a compact subset, which is uncountable.

Comment: @user48672 What about my question? Even though the OP specified that he want $h$ to vary, it still baffles me how you managed to conclude that a non-constant $f$ implies $\{d_h\}$ countable if $h$ is fixed.

Comment: Suppose that $f (x)$ is analytic.  Then it has a Taylor expansion since we hold $h$ fixed eventually we arrive at a polynomial equation for $d_h$ $$ \sum_n {{\mathit{d_h}}^{n}} n {{a}_{n}}=\sum_n {{h}^{n}} {{a}_{n}}$$

Comment: @user48672 So you somehow managed to prove that for a linear function $f$, $\{d_h\}$ is countable? (assume $h$ fixed, of course)

Comment: @user48672 I don't fully understand your reasoning, but maybe you should check it since it leads to an incorrect result.

Comment: I am sorry the edit got lost. for n=1 obviously we have an identity. I will specify that I mean analytic function.